# updating a record from two different records from the same table

Tags: sql

Kindly note that for each CardNo I want extraamt for the smallest date and pendamt+trnamt for the current date and put the sum of them into Recamt, and you want to update all Rows of the CardNo with the same Recamt valuem I used this update query for the same but it is throwing the below error:
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

The query is:

```
update  Tbl_Emi   set  RecAmt =
 (
select
(select extraamt from Tbl_Emi e1 where LastRecDate=(SELECT MIN(lastrecdate) FROM Tbl_Emi) and e1.CardNo=e.CardNo  ) 
+
(select pendamt+trnammt from Tbl_Emi e2 where LastRecDate=(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) and e2.CardNo=e.CardNo )
from Tbl_Emi e where e.lastrecdate=(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
)
where CardNo=
(
select
(select CardNo from Tbl_Emi e2 where LastRecDate=(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) and e2.CardNo=e.CardNo)
from Tbl_Emi e where e.lastrecdate=(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
)
and lastrecdate=(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Comment: A non-working query doesn't always do a good job of describing what you want to do.

Comment: Fair enough, I have the row cardno that is appearing twice but with diffrent dates records, so I want to update in the row recamt where the date is todays date the sum of the extraamt which is for the same cardno but in min(date) with the sum of the pendamt and trnammt in todays date, I hope this clear now.